# Размер плавающего фрейма в ячейке таблицы в зависимости от содержимого

Tags: html, iframe

Здравствуйте, коллеги!
Мой сайт построен на основе 1 таблицы. Одним из ее элементов является плавающий фрейм. Как сделать так, чтобы их размеры (высота ячейки таблицы и фрейма) задавались в зависимости от содержимого?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фреймы?! Вы в каком веке живёте? :)
Это можно дома побаловаться, а в интернет это выкладывать незачем(**!**). Лучше почитайте пару топиков на форумах про **php** и **js**, реализовать будет проще.

Заменители фреймов в
php **->** echo
js **->** innerHTML

Читайте...